# json='{\"key\": \"value\"}' in bash rejected by server with curl -d $json

Tags: json, bash, curl

I am providing a snippet of a bash script that's called at some regular interval.  I cannot seem to get the JSON that must be submitted to be properly escaped (web server says required field is missing):

```
url="http://myurl"
json='{\"rollingRestartStrategy\":\"\"}'

request_cmd="$(curl -u ${CATTLE_ACCESS_KEY}:${CATTLE_SECRET_KEY} -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -d $json $url)"

output=$(echo "$request_cmd")
```

**Error message:**

```
{"id":"04723a42-c2b4-4181-839d-a8ca5180434b","type":"error","links":{},"actions":{},"status":422,"code":"MissingRequired","message":null,"detail":null,"fieldName":"rollingRestartStrategy","baseType":"error"}
```

Comment: Run `echo "$json"` and the problem is obvious.

Comment: ...well, *one* of the problems. Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ for some of the others.

Comment: and `output=$(echo "$request_cmd")` does nothing useful whatsoever; you could just have called the variable `output=$(curl ...)` instead of assigning `request_cmd` in the first place.

Comment: (...and beyond that, `var2=$(echo "$var1")` introduces bugs that just `var2=$var1` wouldn't have; if `var1='-n'` or contains literal backslashes, [output from `echo` is undefined by the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), and varies between implementations).

Answer (score 2):

#### Fixing The Assignment (As Literal Data)

Double quotes are already literal inside single quotes. You don't need to escape them further with backslashes (and *can't*, because when inside single quotes those backslashes are also literal -- which is to say, parsed as data rather than as syntax).

```
# THIS IS BAD; the value assigned is: {\"rollingRestartStrategy\":\"\"} -- not valid JSON
json='{\"rollingRestartStrategy\":\"\"}'

# THIS IS GOOD: the value assigned is: {"rollingRestartStrategy":""}
json='{"rollingRestartStrategy":""}'
```

#### Fixing The Assignment (If Passing Shell Variables)

Let's say that instead of being a literal value, you *actually* want to use a shell variable to set the strategy. In that case, the best practice is to use `jq`:

```
strategy="whatever"
json=$(jq -cn --arg strategy "$strategy" '{ "rollingRestartStrategy": $strategy }')
```

This will generate well-formed JSON *for every possible `strategy`* -- even values that contain literal quotes, literal newlines, or other surprising weirdness.

#### Fixing The Usage

Always, *always* quote expansions (except in a scenario that specifically doesn't require it -- such as assignments, which are immune from expansion-time string-splitting and glob expansion even when unquoted). And note that command substitution with `$()` creates a new quoting context, so quotes used *inside* a command substitution won't interact with quotes used outside it.

```
output=$(curl -u "${CATTLE_ACCESS_KEY}:${CATTLE_SECRET_KEY}" \
              -X POST \
              -H 'Accept: application/json' \
              -d "$json" \
              "$url")
```